# Re-entering Germany after visa expire

Tags: visas, germany, residency

I had a Type D Study Schengen Visa that expired on 25 April 2022, I planned to re-enter Germany on 24 April but the prices were extremely high.

I had already applied for residence permit and I have been informed that it is ready and I can pick it up once I arrive in Germany.

Now the office where I applied for the residence permit sent me a certificate declaring that I applied for residence permit, but I was informed that this does not guarantee re-entry normally.

In my situation, what can I do to ensure re-entry?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you now (Schengen, non-Schengen) and what's your nationality (does it give you visa free access to the Schengen area?)? What is the exact title of the certificate they give you (Fiktionsbescheinigung?) and what fields or remarks are included in that certificate (e.g. section number of the law etc.)?

Comment: I am now in Romania, I am from Egypt, so I require a visa for Germany.  This is what it says: Eine 
Fiktionswirkung nach § 81 Abs. 3 Satz 1 bzw. Abs. 4 Satz 1 AufenthG ist eingetreten

Comment: Do you have a document that look like this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiktionsbescheinigung#/media/Datei:Fiktionsbescheinigung-Traegervordruck.jpg? If so, which box (Abs. 3 or 4) is checked? If it was your first application of residence permit, then it is likely under Abs. 3, which does not allow you to re-enter. A new visa is then needed, but should be faciliated. You could try discuss with the foreigner's office whether a trusted friend or relative can pick the residence card on your behalf and then send that to you.

Comment: I have a regular email PDF from the foreigner authority, and it says: Es wird bescheinigt, dass die oben genannte Person einen Antrag auf Erteilung bzw. Verlängerung eines Aufenthaltstitels bei der Ausländerbehörde des Landratsamts  hat. Eine 
Fiktionswirkung nach § 81 Abs. 3 Satz 1 bzw. Abs. 4 Satz 1 AufenthG ist eingetreten. Der Aufenthalt ist daher rechtmäßig.
Die Erteilung bzw. Verlängerung des Aufenthaltstitels wird verfahrensbedingt noch etwas Zeit 
in Anspruch nehmen. 
Diese Bescheinigung ist ab Ausstellungsdatum einen Monat gültig.

Answer (score 2):

If it is your first time applying for a German residence permit and do not have a Fiktionbescheinigung issued under § 81 Abs. 4 Satz 1, you need a valid visa or residence permit to return to the Schengen Area, unless your nationality is exempt from visa and you still have "days" left for short stays. A PDF does not suffice and is unlikely to be recognized by airlines or a border guard at a land border (they may not even speak German).

You can either ask if it is possible for a trusted friend or relative to pick up your residence permit and courier it to you; if not, ask if it is possible for the German embassy/consulate to expedite a return visa based on the issued residence permit (even if not in your possession); if still not possible, you need to follow the embassy's directions on how to obtain a new visa.